# The location of the origin in OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm getting started with OpenGL ES in Android and I'm running into a situation that I don't quite understand. The origin in OpenGL should be the lower-left corner of the screen, correct? Because for me, it appears to be in the middle of the screen. So far, I've just worked around it by translating and rotating to the coordinate system I want, but I'd like an understanding of why this is happening in the first place. Below, this is a minimal example that will place the sprite in the dead center of the screen. I'm not performing any translations or rotations in this code.

```
package com.lyrismobilestudio.opengltest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        Renderer renderer = new MyRenderer(this);
        view.setRenderer(renderer);
        setContentView(view);
    }
}

class MyRenderer implements Renderer {
    public Sprite strike;
    public Context context;

    public MyRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        strike = new Sprite();
    }

    @Override public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClearColor(.5f,.5f,1f,0f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        strike.draw(gl);
        try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    @Override public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height){
    }

    @Override public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig arg1) {
        strike.loadTexture(gl, R.drawable.strike, context);
    }
}

class Sprite {
    FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    ByteBuffer indexBuffer;
    private int[] textures = new int[1];

    public Sprite() {
        float[] vertices = {
            -.1f,  .1f,
            .1f,  .1f,
            .1f, -.1f,
            -.1f, -.1f,
        };
        float[] textureVertices = new float[]{
            0f, 0f,
            1f, 0f,
            1f, 1f,
            0f, 1f
        };
        byte indices[] = {
            0, 1, 2,
            0, 2, 3
        };
        ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);
        temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = temp.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);
        temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureVertices.length*4);
        temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = temp.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(textureVertices);
        textureBuffer.position(0);
        indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
        indexBuffer.put(indices);
        indexBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl){
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }

    public void loadTexture(GL10 gl, int texture, Context context){
        InputStream imageStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(texture);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            try {  
                imageStream.close();
                imageStream=null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

Comment: the viewport coordinates are from [-1,1] in both x and y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL, by default, uses a viewport onto your screen that covers the co-ordinate range -1 to +1  for both the x and y axis. Therefore the origin is in the centre of the screen. Note that because the co-ordinate range is the same for x and y, your objects will appear stretched (unless your screen is square...). An excellent illustration can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

To cater for the geometry of your screen (and to view objects drawn outside the -1/+1 range), you'll want to introduce a projection matrix. Then you will need a camera transformation matrix as well which defines where in your coordinate space you are looking from, and in what direction.

Comment: Okay then, so it's the expected behavior? I can accept that. The books I've read all said that it would be in the bottom-left, but I'm okay with it if it isn't. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't messing anything up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The origin is in the center of the screen. X points right, Y points up, and Z points out of the screen. Since you aren't changing the projection matrix, it goes from -1 to 1 in each direction.